# Comments and likes for a photo not showing up on Facebook profile, only when clicking the photo

Tags: facebook, photos, comments

On Facebook, I noticed that the comments and likes for a photo I checked in are not showing up on my profile but they display when I click into the photo.

How can I get them to display directly on my profile?

Comment: I don't think it shows up in your main timeline but in the Ticker on the side. I could be wrong on this.

Comment: Was it from a photo that you were tagged in due to a check-in to a place?

Answer (score 1):

The likes and comments on the photo visible in your profile/timeline because of you being tagged there/checked in/you shared that photo is one thing.

And the likes and comments on the actual photo (in the Facebook Page or Facebook Profile of the actual up-loader) is a completely different thing.

When you click on the photo in your Profile/Timeline, you go to the kind-of-full-screen-view-of-the-actual-photo.

In your Profile/Timeline you will see only the likes and comments that people posted on the photo through your Profile/Timeline (by visiting your Profile/Timeline). Also these likes and comments are not added to the actual photo.