# Likes on a picture not showing up

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comments and likes for a photo not showing up on Facebook profile, only when clicking the photo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25444/comments-and-likes-for-a-photo-not-showing-up-on-facebook-profile-only-when-cli)

On my phone is says that I have 12 likes on a picture, but when I get on my Facebook on my computer it only says I have 6 likes.  What do I need to do to make all my likes show up on a picture?

Comment: try clearing your cache (CTRL + SHIFT + DEL). That usually does the trick.

Comment: Is your case same as: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/27324/19533

Answer (score 1):

Be patient. Sometimes it needs a little time to show up.